# How to change top margin for UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin

I have a toolbar in my view. it contains a Bar button item with an icon, actually it's not an icon (it's a custom font). I'm using it to unify the icons with other web application for the same customer.

Anyway, how could I increase the top margin a little bit ... maybe the given example is showing a filter icon that I can easily replace it with real image icon (not a font). But some other icons, it's impossible.

[image: Filter Icon in toolbar]

**Edit 1:**

I'm using C# (Xamarin). Even if there is an object-c code. I'm ok with it.

```
var att = new UITextAttributes ();
att.Font = FontHelper.GetIconFont (32.0f);
this.btnFilter.SetTitleTextAttributes (att, UIControlState.Normal);
```

the custom icon font method:

```
public static UIFont GetIconFont(float size) 
{
    var nfloatSize = nfloat.Parse (((float)size).ToString ());
    return UIFont.FromName(_fontIcons, nfloatSize);
}
```

Comment: Can you also show your code on how you added the item? I may have some ideas but at least want to see your code first.

Comment: Hi @SanitLee .. please check my update "Edit 1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking of the way of doing subclass UINavigationBar and override layoutSubviews and reposition the UIBarButtonItem. Also, don't forget to set UINavigationBar class to UINavigationBar subclass in Interface Builder. So you may try something like this:

```
// UINavigationBar subclass    
#define NAVIGATION_MARGIN 3 

@implementation NewNavigationBar

- (void)layoutSubviews {

    [super layoutSubviews];
    UINavigationItem *navigationItem = [self topItem];
    subview = [[navigationItem leftBarButtonItem] customView];

    if (subview) {
        CGRect subviewFrame = subview.frame;
        subview.frame.origin.x = NAVIGATION_BTN_MARGIN;
        subview.frame.origin.y = (self.frame.size.height - subview.frame.size.height) / 2;
        [subview setFrame:subviewFrame];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Looks like i should create a custom view, then i can control it. 
But if your custom icon font (like 'font awesome') has some settings that makes font goes up. then custom ui is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this,

```
float offset = 3.0f;

UIBarButtonItem * barItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" 
                                                      style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                                      target:nil action:@selector(someMessage)];

[barItem setBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment:offset forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: Thank you @Mayank for your answer. I tried it but it's not working with me :( ... As I said in the question this is not Icon or Image. This is a simple text (let say like font awesome (e.g. https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/). So it's custom font. ... So I believe that setBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment used for icons .. right?!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what language your working in but use the `backgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment` property of `UIBarButtonItem`.

```
button.setBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment(3.0, forBarMetrics: .Default)
```

Answer (score 0):

When using text / Ionicons, the following is what's needed to reposition the icon ( Xamarin code below ):

```
button.SetTitlePositionAdjustment(
    new UIOffset() { Vertical = 15.0f, Horizontal = 5.0f },
    UIBarMetrics.Default );
```